# Proving cube-root of two is not a rational number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand well how to prove this in the normal fashion. However I’m stuck on how to prove this when defining $Q$ as $Z x N$ partitioned into equivalence classes.

For example if I assume $q^3 = [(q_1^3,q_2^3)]=[(2,1)]$ I’m not sure how to prove it considering I can’t assume $q_1$ and $q_2$ is in its “simplest form” since it doesn’t have to be due to the definition of the equivalence class.

Comment: Spell out that $(q_1^3,q_2^3)\sim (2,1)$ and take it from there

Comment: Working with this I find q1 and q2 are both divisible by two. But I don’t see how this has significance as it belongs to an equivalence class that could contain the simplified version

Comment: In that case I find $q_1^3=2q_2^3$ which shows $q_1^3$ and therefore $q_1$ is even. In turn I find $q_2$ is even. How can this be of any use in the proof if there’s nothing I can assume about $[(_1,_2)]$ being in its simplest form since it need not be due to it being an equivalence class.

Comment: you could work with a representative of the equivalence class, and given any representative you could find another one in simplest form.

Answer (score 1):

You have $q_1=2^m X$ with $X$ odd and $m\ge 0$, and $q_2=2^n Y$ with Y odd and $n\ge 0$. Therefore $q_1^3 = 2q_2^3 \implies 2^{3m}X^3 = 2^{3n+1}Y^3$. Since both $X$ and $Y$ are odd, this means $2^{3m} = 2^{3n+1}$, that is, $3m=3n+1$. But $3m$ is a multiple of $3$ while $3n+1$ isn't, therefore both cannot be equal.

Comment: Why does X,Y odd imply $2^{3m}=2^{3n+1}$?

Comment: @Anteater23: Because of the uniqueness of prime factorization. An odd number doesn't have a factor $2$ (that's the defnition of odd), therefore all factors of $2$ come from the $2^{3m}$ resp. $2^{3n+1}$ terms. Uniqueness of prime factorization therefore implies that both must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

if both q1 and q2 are divisible by 2 then there cannot exist a coprime ratio. Take for example _/2=a/b or _/2=q1/q2 . For the square root of two to be rational the largest prime number both integers should be able to be divisible by is 1, but, both share two as a common factor. Ergo _/2 cannot be rational. hope that helped?

Comment: I’m not struggling with this form of proof but thanks anyway.